# Is Kafka cluster a database?

Tags: apache-kafka

1. What does cluster mean?
2. The doc says `The Kafka cluster *stores* streams of records in categories called topics`.
3. If it stores, then is it a database?

Comment: There's a video on this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2RJQELoM6Y

Comment: As a follow-up question, your filesystem "stores" files, so is that a database? Hint: there are more conditions than just storing things to call it a database

Comment: worth to read : https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-streaming-sql-for-apache-kafka/

Comment: @sun KSQL is a processing layer, not a database or treats Kafka as one

Answer (score 2):

1. cluster means multiple machines that "share the load" among them. this is deliberately vague as there are many ways of achieving this.
2. what is the question here?
3. (disclaimer - my opinion and generally subjective) its a database in the broadest sense of it stores data, and you can get the data back out. however, since it lacks any real "fetch by PK" or query facilities it makes for a very bad choice of primary storage for most use cases and is usually used as an intermediate bus rather than a source of truth.